# Convert daily (date) format to hourly (posixct)

Tags: r, join, posixct

I have a data frame with daily data. I need to bind it to hourly data, but first I need to convert it to a suitable posixct format. This looks like this:

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2015-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), to = as.Date("2015-01-29", "%Y-%m-%d"), by = "day"),
  var1 = runif(29, min = 5, max = 10)
)

result <- data.frame(
  Date = d <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = ""), 
                         to = as.POSIXct("2015-01-29 23:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = ""), by = "hour"),
  var1 =  rep(df$var1, each = 24) )
```

However, my data is not as easy to work with as the above. I have lots of missing dates, so I need to be able to take the specific `df$Date`-vector and convert it to a posixct frame, with the matching daily values.

I've looked high and low but been unable to find anything on this.

Comment: Maybe `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, .(Date = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, 0:23), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H"), var1), by = 1:nrow(df)]`?

Comment: you should add missing data to your example if you want people to help you on this aspect.

Comment: in fact I do not understand why do you want to generate all possible hours within a day. If you want to bind it with another data frame with hours, you should do the opposite -> in the df, add a new bind field with the date without hours to be able to merge with your current df.

Comment: The point is to generate a hourly frame - and fill out the values - by extending the daily data. How would merging with daily data help that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I went about this was to find the min and max of the dataset and deem them hour 0 and hour 23.

```
hourly <- data.frame(Hourly=seq(min(as.POSIXct(paste0(df$Date, "00:00:00"),tz="")),max(as.POSIXct(paste0(df$Date, "23:00:00"),tz="")),by="hour"))
hourly[,"Var1"] <- df[match(x = as.Date(hourly$Hourly),df$Date),"var1"]
```

This achieves a result of the daily values becoming hourly with the daily var1 assigned to each hour that contains the day. In this respect missing daily values should not be an issue and if there is no match, it will add in NA's.